# vaadin7 File upload only jpeg

Tags: java

vaadin7 File upload only jpeg
how to set filter only jpeg and selected file only allow jpeg image only.
easy upload multiple file upload' upload.setAcceptFilter(".jpg,.JPG")'; are used same as what type code add only show jpeg display

upload.setMimeType("JPEG")

Comment: Hello there, explain your question in details. It's not clear now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.